# Can I stop /usr/bin/mail from putting lots of binary data in syslog

Tags: linux, logs, raspberry-pi, email

I'm running Linux 9 on a Raspberry Pi Model 3B.

Periodically via CRONTAB, I start a task to email (/usr/bin/mail) some files.  The task in working and I get the files.  However, it is also logging binary data in the SYSLOG for the attachments. This results in the SYSLOG becoming very large and almost unusable.  How can I suppress this logging to SYSLOG?

Edit/update Aug 21, 2022
Below are some additional information as requested by one of the commenters.

Here is the command line in CRONTAB:

```
0 0 * * * /usr/pgms/sendtome.sh "PiV2"  "AcuritePgmLog.txt;todaydata.txt;rainfall3.txt;Acurite_error.log;"  > /mnt/usbdrive/output/CRON_output.txt 2>&1
```

Here is the sendtome.sh script:

````
cat /usr/pgms/sendtome.sh
#!/bin/bash
MyPath="/mnt/usbdrive/output/"
TO="xx@hotmail.com"
MESSAGEx="Midnight `date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'` $HOSTNAME Pi report"
echo $MESSAGEx
temp=$(echo $2 | tr ";" "\n")
for file in $temp
do
    echo "> [$file]"
done
/usr/bin/mysql -uxyz -pzz -e "select * from pidata WHERE (Date_Reading > DATE_ADD((SELECT MAX(Date_Reading) FROM pidata), INTERVAL -3 HOUR))" acurite > /mnt/usbdrive/output/todaydata.txt
declare -a attargs
for att in $temp; do
  x=$MyPath$att
  echo $x
  attargs+=( "-A" "$x" )
done
echo ${attargs[@]}
echo $MESSAGEx | /usr/bin/mail -s "$1" "$TO" ${attargs[@]}```
````

Here is the CRON_output.txt file:

```
cat /mnt/usbdrive/output/CRON_output.txt
Midnight 2022-08-21 00:00:02 CEST PiV2 Pi report
> [AcuritePgmLog.txt]
> [todaydata.txt]
> [rainfall3.txt]
> [Acurite_error.log]
/mnt/usbdrive/output/AcuritePgmLog.txt
/mnt/usbdrive/output/todaydata.txt
/mnt/usbdrive/output/rainfall3.txt
/mnt/usbdrive/output/Acurite_error.log
-A /mnt/usbdrive/output/AcuritePgmLog.txt -A /mnt/usbdrive/output       /todaydata.txt -A /mnt/usbdrive/output/rainfall3.txt -A /mnt/usbdrive/output/Acurite_error.log
```

And finally here is an excerpt from last nights syslog file on the Pi.  The lines before that were similar content to the first line below:

```
Aug 21 00:00:23 PiV2 sSMTP[10264]: IHRvIGh0dHA6Ly93d3cucmRrc2Nvcm5lci5jb20vcmRrL2FzcC9QaUFsbERhdGFXcml0ZTJGaWxl
Aug 21 00:00:23 PiV2 sSMTP[10264]: QWN1cml0ZV9CYXR0ZXJ5LmFzcDogRXJyb3IgIyB0aW1lZCBvdXQK
Aug 21 00:00:23 PiV2 sSMTP[10264]: --2113075354-1661032807=:10262--
Aug 21 00:00:23 PiV2 sSMTP[10264]: .
Aug 21 00:00:28 PiV2 sSMTP[10264]: 250 2.0.0 OK  1661032828 p8-20020a17090653c800b007305d408b3dsm607286ejo.78 - gsmtp
Aug 21 00:00:28 PiV2 sSMTP[10264]: QUIT
Aug 21 00:00:28 PiV2 sSMTP[10264]: 221 2.0.0 closing connection p8-20020a17090653c800b007305d408b3dsm607286ejo.78 - gsmtp
Aug 21 00:00:28 PiV2 sSMTP[10264]: Sent mail for xx@PiV2 (221 2.0.0 closing connection p8-20020a17090653c800b007305d408b3dsm607286ejo.78 - gsmtp) uid=1001 username=xx outbytes=1962655
```

I hope this helps to explain the situation.  Oh yes, here is the SSMTP.conf file

```
 cat /etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf
# Config file for sSMTP sendmail
# The person who gets all mail for userids < 1000
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
root=
# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
# Where will the mail seem to come from?
#rewriteDomain=
# The full hostname
hostname=PiV2
# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address
#FromLineOverride=YES
AuthUser=bbb@gmail.com
AuthPass=123456789012
FromLineOverride=YES
UseSTARTTLS=YES
UseTLS=YES
Debug=YES
```

...RDK

Comment: I doubt we can help here without a clue about the actual crontab script....

Comment: If you are running syslog, such as syslog-ng or rsylog, these have config files in which you can trap certain data. You may see lines referencing mail already, just change the destination to /dev/null.If you are using systemd to log this stuff, then good luck with that... Regardless though, it should not be logging binary data for attachments, these are not even binary, but base64 encoded. If it's doing that then check your emailer. It may be that you are calling the email program wrongly.

Comment: I will update my question with more info